# Comparing int and char with cast

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Why doesn't the function print "true" when '1' is input for both variables? How can I fix this?

```
int main() {
    int i;
    char c;
    cout << "Type int: ";
    cin  >> i;
    cout << "Type char: ";
    cin  >> c;
    if (i == (int)c)
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "false" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other input stream objects, `std::cin` is designed to work differently when you read into different types.

For an `int`, it reads the numbers you write into the console and parses them into internal integer form. This is convenient: "formatted extraction" means we get a useful `int` right away and don't need to any conversions from string to number.

For a `char`, it reads the actual letter or digit or punctuation that you wrote into the console; it does not parse it. It simply stores that character. In this case, `c` is 49 because that is the ASCII value of `'1'`.

If you wanted to see whether the `int` contained `1` and the `char` contained `'1'` to match, then you can exploit the property of ASCII that all the digits are found in sequential order starting from 48, or `'0'`:

```
if (`i` == `c`-'0')
```

However, if you do this, you should verify that:

- Your platform uses ASCII;
- `c` contains a digit (`'0', '1', ..., '9'`).

Generally avoid these hacks if you can. There's usually another way to check your inputs.

Comment: I would like the function to print 'true' when equal values are input ie char = '2' and int = 2, and false when different values are input. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `char` is an integer type, it is treated by the `>>` operator differently from other integer types.

- For non-char integer recipient variable the `>>` operator treats the input as a representation of an integer value. The entire representation is consumed from the input, converted to integer and stored in the recepient variable. For example, if you enter `8` as the input, the recipient variable (say, an `int`) will receive integer value `8`. If you enter `42` as the input, the recipient variable will receive integer value `42`.
- But for `char` recipient variable the `>>` operator treats the input as a mere character sequence. Only the first character of that sequence is consumed and immediately stored in the recipient variable. For example, if you enter `8` as the input, a `char` recipient variable will receive *character* `'8'`, which corresponds to integer value of `56`. If you enter `42` as the input, the recipient variable will receive character `'4'`, which corresponds to integer value of `52`.

That is what leads to the inequality in your case.